# Is it disadvantage if my first graduate job is outside of current country?

Tags: job-search, graduate

I'm currently on a placement year (between year 2 and 3) of my university degree in England, on a software engineering course. I have been here since I was a child (I am Polish), so I am very used to my life in the UK.

I do not see a future here after Brexit, and so I am looking at alternative options. The most common English-speaking countries (US and Canada) are too far for me to consider, and the lack of health-care in US makes it a big no-no. That leaves me European countries which are quite developed, such as Sweden, Netherlands, Denmark, Belgium, Luxembourg etc. to consider.

Will I be able to settle in better if I first get some experience here, in England, or if it is better to start there? Are graduate positions in foreign countries advertised for re-locators, or should I expect only positions with some experience being advertised in English? If so, how can I go about my job-search?

Comment: Do you have the right to remain - id sort that our first

Answer (score 4):

Experience is experience no matter where you go. Besides, working for someone **cannot** look bad on your CV unless you get fired for cause.

With that said, the countries you are thinking of moving to are not primarily-English-speaking countries. You will want to get at least some basic training in the primary language of the country you reside in.

Most European countries have a health system similar to how the US one is *supposed* to operate (health insurance is a common/basic thing like in the US, but is also really affordable, for instance), so while you may see similarities that give you cause for concern in that regard, it is not nearly as bad.

There are many recruitment agencies dedicated to prospective expats like yourself, so start your job search with a conversation with those companies.

Another big problem is going to be Brexit itself, assuming you are a UK citizen, as with Brexit will likely come the removal of your automatic right to work in an EU country. Not all of the EU countries have fully formed policies with what to do with British expats yet, but it seems the worst case scenario is you'll need to be able to get a work visa for most countries. If, on the off-chance you are eligible for a passport from another EU country, I would apply for one, as it will really save on headaches (and potential rejections due to such headaches) in the application process.

Comment: erm.. while I'm not saying I disagree with what you are saying I'm curious as to how you drew the NHS connection since the OP makes no mention of this? They would also be unlikely to ever find themselves in a position to be "struck off" since in an NHS context that's something that applies to doctors and nurses not software engineers.

Comment: Ahh, silly me. I saw healthcare an assumed that was OP's field. Mornings are not good to me. Editing now

Comment: no worries.. I have the same problem - I was assuming there had been something I had missed!

Answer (score 0):

One particular example when this will be a disadvantage is following:

1. You hate country X, but that is the only one that offered you good job
2. You go to X, learn their language, culture, establish contacts, spend 5 years there
3. You are fed up with X, and interviewed for the job back at home in the UK for large corporation
4. They are super excited and hire you
5. They know you are familiar with X and, -- what is that? They just opened office in X and you will help set it up!
6. Congratulations, you have another 5-year long gig in X, which you still hate, and your spouse/significant other/children have to move from UK

Similar situation, but less annoying is:

6. You spend every other week in X to help set things up for several years

This situation sometime happens to expats: people from other country hired by European corp, they are being sent back home to work, consult or whatever, because they speak language and know culture.

You might want to consider if that situation applies to you